# Power BI: Plot data without calculated y axis

Tags: plot, powerbi

I would like to plot data on power bi but every time I try by using line chart y axis values are calculated eitger as sum, average or whatever else I choose but I need to have only raw values to show how level changes over time.

Sample data:
Level - y axis
Datetime - x axis

| Level | Datetime |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 2023-02-28 08:00 |
| 1 | 2023-03-02 09:05 |
| 2 | 2023-03-02 11:40 |
| 1 | 2023-03-05 08:45 |

Tried line chart different settings but with no luck. Maybe there od didferent object I could use but I could not find it

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one Level per Datetime value, then the SUM doesn't matter. You are summing **one data point only**, so the SUM will always be equal to that data point (in your case, the level)

It is important for a Line Chart to use aggregate values when needed, because it is not possible to show *2 distinct values in Y-Axis against one distinct value in X-Axis*, therefore you will not have an option to "Don't Summarize" in Line Chart. However, as I said earlier, if you don't want your records to be "summarized", then simply make sure that you have only one value in Y-Axis against every value in X-Axis. In this way, aggregation wouldn't affect your results.

I used your dataset and plotted it in a Line Chart and got this result (with SUM of Level as Aggregation)

[image]

As you can see, there are four distinct values in Y-Axis, against the four distinct values in X-Axis. Now, you can simply change the "Name" of the "SUM of Level" to "Level" from the Fields Column and you are good to go. (However, do make sure that in future, you don't get two values of Level against one distinct value of Datetime, otherwise your line chart will be disturbed)

Comment: Thanks, this was probably my mistake. I had two values at the same date

Comment: @TeresaSergiel If you are using datetime (like you are in this case), then two dates with different times will be treated as two different points (that is, if first point is 02-03-2023 5:00 and second is 02-03-2023 6:00, they will be treated as two different points. So you are ok as long as you use datetime datatype). 
If the reply solves your issue, do mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: I do not knows why but power bi creates from my datetime date hierarchy which do not have time. So even if they are different based on time, on date level are the same and as a result agregated. Any idea how I can fix it?

Comment: @TeresaSergiel Click on your "Date" from the "Fields" and then click on "Show as Date". Power BI automatically shows Date in Date Hierarchy but you can easily change it from your Fields Pane. Let me know in case of any confusion in it

Comment: With datetime I have too much gradiation. So it looks like I need to have at least only date on x axis but not agregated on y axis so it means that in case of two the same dates plot should show show two points for the same date
Level: 0,1 Date: 2023-02-28 08:00 , 2023-02-28 09:05